# calculate annual and monthly interest

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
interest = int(float(raw_input("Interest Rate: ")))
monintrate = int(float(( interest / 100.0 ) / 12))
annintrate = int(float(interest / 12))

print "Interest: ",interest
print "Mon Int Rate: ",monintrate
print "Ann Int Rate: ",annintrate
```

hello, i would like to properly calculate the above variables as decimals but for whatever reason i cant get it work correctly. can someone point me in the right direction?

Below are my results:

```
Interest: 5
Mon Int Rate: 0
Ann Int Rate: 0
```

thank you

Answer (score 1):

Remove the int before the variables so you can get decimals

```
interest = float(raw_input("Interest Rate: "))
monintrate = float(( interest / 100.0 ) / 12)
annintrate = float(interest / 12)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get rid of the `int`

```
interest = float(raw_input("Interest Rate: "))
monintrate = round((interest / 100.0)/12, 4) """ will give 4 decimal places"""
annintrate = round((interest / 12), 4)       """ will give 4 decimal places"""

print "Interest: ",interest
print "Mon Int Rate: ",monintrate
print "Ann Int Rate: ",annintrate
```

Gives the following:

```
Interest:  5.0
Mon Int Rate:  0.0042
Ann Int Rate:  0.41667
```

Comment: in order to format monintrate (Mon Int Rate) could i do this: print "Monthly Int Rate: ",'{0:.2g}'.format(monintrate)

Comment: I'll edit my answer now but you can use the `round()` function.

Answer (score 0):

this will do

```
print month,"___","{:.2f}".format(monprnpaid),"___","{:.2f}".format(monintdue),"___","{:.2f}".format(loanbal)
```

thanks everyone